# A variation on the 1985 B2 Putnam problem.

Tags: calculus, polynomials, contest-math

Recently I together with a friend solved problem 14 of [https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/myputnam.pdf](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/myputnam.pdf) by using an inductive approach.  However we got stuck on a variation of the problem where the variation states that:

> $f_0(x)=1, f_{n+1}(x)=xf_n(x)+f'_n(x)$

Thinking of using an inductive approach a few $f_n$s were worked out where:

1. $f_1(x)=x$
2. $f_2(x)=1+x^2$
3. $f_3(x)=3x+x^3$
4. $f_4(x)=3+6x^2+x^4$
5. $f_5(x)=15x+10x^3+x^5$
6. $f_6(x)=15+45x^2+15x^4+x^6$
7. $f_7(x)=105x+105x^3+21x^5+x^7$
8. $f_8(x)=105+420x^2+210x^4+28x^6+x^8$
9. $f_9(x)=945x+1260x^3+378x^5+36x^7+x^9$
10. $f_{10}(x)=945+4725x^2+3150x^4+630x^6+45x^8+x^{10}$

First some patterns were noticed.

1. The constant term of $f_{2n}$ is $(2n-1)!!$ for any non zero values of $2n$. For example the constant term of $f_{10}$ is $1⋅3⋅5⋅7⋅9$.
2. For any 2n large enough the coefficient of $x^2$ is $n⋅(2n-1)!!$
3. The leading coefficient of any $f_n$ is $1$.
4. The coefficient of the term with degree $n-2$ in $f_n$ forms a quadratic sequence  specifically $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.
5. The equation is that defines $f_{n+1}$ is in the form of an integrating factor.
6. The degree of $f_n$ is $n$ and if $n$ is odd then all terms with odd degree has non zero coefficient. Similarly if $n$ is even then all terms with even degree has non zero coefficient.
7. All $f_n$ are polynomials.

For 7., 6., 5., 4., 3. we were able to prove is true mostly by using induction on n. From the statement of the problem it suffices to prove that 1. is true. However when we tried to prove it we ran into some problems.

"**Proof.**"

There is a clear relationship between $f_n$ and $f_{n+1}$ given in the problem so we thought of induction. Assumption: For any $n\neq 0$ the constant term of $f_{2n}$ is $(2n-1)!!$.

From our computation the base case of $n=1$ is true. It suffices to prove that our assumption holds for $n+1$. By using the relationship between $f_n$ and $f_{n+1}$ given in the problem we see that

> $f_{2(n+1)}(x)=x^2f_{2n}(x)+xf'_{2n}(x)+f_{2n}(x)+xf'_{2n}(x)+f''_{2n}(x)$

Notice that the only terms in the sum that contributes to the constant term of $f_{2(n+1)}$ are the terms $f_{2n}$ and $f''_{2n}$. However we don't know the coefficient of $x^2$ in $f_{2n}$. $\blacksquare$

From this failed proof it seems that we would also need to include 2. in our assumption. However when we do that we would need to know the coefficient of $x^4$ in $f_{2n}$. This is where we got stuck. It seems that one would need to know the coefficient of every term in this problem to be able to finish the induction. The relationship between the coefficients of $f_n$ and $f_{n+1}$ feels similar to the relationship of the terms in Pascal's triangle, but I am not sure. This is where we got stuck. Do anyone know how to solve this problem? Any solution, proof and help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hey you can refer mits pyq website for help

Comment: Hi @Mathslover I do not know what is the "mits pyq website" and searching it up did not produce a useful result. Do you mind providing a link? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the notion of generatrice function? Your interesting noticed patterns could maybe to lead to a such generatrice function of $f$ (*being given by a recurrence relation*). Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Have you seen the solution to the original putnam question? Some of them guess and prove an explicit formula for $f_n(x)$, so maybe give that a try? $\quad$ Another pattern like the coefficient of $x^{n-2}$ is $1\times {n \choose 2}$ is that the coefficient of $x^{n-4}$ is $1\times 3 {n \choose 4}$, and likewise for $x^{n-6}$ is $1\times 3 \times 5 \times { n \choose 6}$. So you could double induct to show that the coefficient of $x^{2n - 2n } $ is $ 1 \times 3 \times 5 \times \ldots \times (2n-1) \times { 2n \choose 2n }$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Brilliant observation! I never noticed that. No wonder the relationship between that coefficients feels similar to the numbers in pascals triangle. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I provided an explicit characterization for the coefficients which could be proved by induction.

---

Hint for a quick solution:  Let $g_n(x) = e^{x^2/2} f_n(x)$.

> Show that $g_n(x) = \frac{d^n}{dx^n} e^{x^2/2}$.

> Hence, $ f_{2n}(0) = g_{2n}(0) = (2n-1)!!$. (requires some work to calculate)

Note: This question is likely motivated by [Hermite polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials), which are of the form $H_n(x) = (-1)^n e^{x^2/2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n} e^{-x^2/2}$.
In fact, the coefficients are equal, up to sign.